# NoMethodError undefined method のエラーが出る

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

初めての質問です。
Ruby on railsで勉強をさせて頂いているのですが
rails sを行いページを見ようとすると下記のようなエラがー出てしまいます。

解決法をお教え頂ければ幸いです。

- ruby v2.2.2
- rails v4.2.5.1

エラー名

```
NoMethodError in ProjectController#show 
undefined method `users' for #<Project:0x007f9ef37c73a8>
```

**app/controllers/project.controller.rb**

```
class ProjectController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:list]

  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @tasks = @project.tasks.order(:tag)

    @joined = false

    if !current_user.nil? && !current_user.projects.nil?
      @joined = current_user.projects.include?(@project)
    end

    @users = @project.users.order('created_at desc').first(10)
  end

  def list    
    if !current_user.nil?
      @projects = current_user.projects
    end
  end
end
```

**app/admin/project.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project do
  permit_params :name, :content, :price, :image

  show do |t|
    attributes_table do
      row :name
      row :content
      row :price
      row :image do
        project.image? ? image_tag(project.image.url, height: '100') : content_tag(:span, "No photo yet")
      end
    end
  end

  form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :name
      f.input :content
      f.input :price  
      f.input :image, hint: f.project.image? ? image_tag(project.image.url, height: '100') : content_tag(:span, "Upload JPG/PNG/GIF image")
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

**app/model/project.rb**

```
    class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]

  has_many :tasks

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500 }
  validates :price, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }

  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "680x300>", :thumb => "170x75>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  def shortname
    name.length > 25? name[0..25] + "..." : name
  end
end
```

app/project/views/project/show.html.rb

Comment: Project クラスに、 users メソッド (または users で呼べるもの) がありませんが、FriendlyId 中で 定義されているのでしょうか？

Comment: @user3758624 FriendlyIdで定義されているかというのはどうやって確認したらよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: 回答として投稿されていたコメントをこちらに移動して、短く編集しました。質問時のアカウントと違う場合、コメント以外にも使えない機能が出てきますから、アカウントのマージもご検討ください： http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/2093/8000

Answer (score 1):

おそらく、`app/model/project.rb`に

```
has_many :users
```

が不足しているのでしょう。

`belongs_to`や`has_many`などの[アソシエーション](http://railsguides.jp/association_basics.html)の意味や使い方について確認されると良いと思います。